# Hiace 1996 ignition/motor problems

Tags: engine, starter, wiring

I have a 1996 Hiace. I was driving and it just died, nothing. Dash lights all work, but motor will not turn over, nothing from starter.

It has dual fuel, and was wondering if it could be the AEB 552 Safety Relay Ref: EAEB-552-SAFETYRELAY. Would this stop the van without anything motor wise working. I have checked the fuses and all look ok, but I don't have testing equipment. What could be the issue?

Comment: Hoping you got this issue resolved.  If so, could you post what the fix was as answer to your own question?  Happy New Years!

Comment: What was the engine temperature like when it cut out? It might be overheating and had to cut out as a safety precaution.